# steal.js not working with jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, stealjs

I am using jquery 1.7.2 which supports raphael.js and highlighter.js and it works fine.
Now when I load steal.js( for dragging a div within specified limits), the jquery becomes void and the mentioned javascripts stop working. I am unable to understand what problem does steal.js create here.

The code for steal.js functionality to drag is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../../javascriptmvc/steal/steal.js'> </script>              
            steal("jquerypp/event/drag",
                "jquerypp/event/drag/scroll",
                "jquerypp/event/drag/limit").then(function(){

             $("#svg-container").delegate(".handle","draginit",function(ev, drag){drag.limit( $("#svg-container") )}) 

            });
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery++ from http://jquerypp.com/?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same.

Comment: Perhaps you should post more of your code to have a better picture, because at this point the only error I can see is that the call to the steal function is outside a script block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stealing any jquerypp feature will also steal jQuery since it is a dependency. If you look at stealconfig.js, you'll see the location Steal is using to retrieve jQuery (by defualt it is can/lib/jquery.1.9.1.js).

Since jQuery exposes itself globally, the jQuery that is stolen is clobbering the one you loaded in the page before using steal.

If you are going to use steal, I'd suggest loading all of your JavaScript files using it.